# Submitting new version of existing app on App Store only for iOS7 users. Is it possible?

Tags: ios, ios7, app-store-connect

Trivial question I know, but I need to figure out this before I actually try it on iTunes Connect.

I have an application on the App Store, I would like that next version of the app is only available to users of iOS7 or greater.

I wonder if simply updating my app info.plist to support > iOS7 is enough to leave existing users running iOS6 with the latest version I released (1.9) before changing info.plist, and instead have iOS7 users prompted (or automatically updated) to the new 2.0 iOS7-only version?

Or maybe there is something else I have to specify under iTunes Connect? 
I can't see anything actually there...

Comment: Yep nothing needs to be done, Apple enabled this feature last year

Comment: Thank you, this is what I wanted to hear!

Comment: @JackWu This has been true since the store opened in 2008. I think you are referring to the ability for people to download older versions of an app if the latest version isn't compatible with their device/iOS version.

Comment: @rmaddy Indeed that was what I was referring to, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is how it works. If you update your app's Deployment Target to iOS 7 then existing iOS 6 users will not be told of an update (and won't be able to update). iOS 7 users will be able to update.